# What kind of larvae are these. Lots of them in the basement in the summer, crawling around on the floor and the walls

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[larvae crawl on basement floor.  Some are also found on the first floor of the house.  Lots of legs--I also thought they became "rolly polys"  but never knew for sure what they were either.[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsU7m.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/86502/edit) your post to: 1) include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better), and 2) an estimate of the size of the creature. The location and size can be essential clues for identification. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature would be helpful. ——— Thank you for taking the tour — please also take the time to go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: "Lots of them in the basement in the summer, crawling around on the floor and the walls" Quick! get some head & shoulders :)

Answer (score 4):

Those are not larvae, but adult millipedes. Myriopoda, Diplopoda. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millipede
Here is a good link from the U of Minnesota on common arthropods in the basement.
https://extension.umn.edu/insect-relatives/sowbugs-millipedes-and-centipedes